# How to create a lookup field that has a list column picker

Tags: 2010, list, visual-studio, lookup-column, field-definition

How would I be able to create a list field in VS that would be a lookup to select columns from any list?

I would preferably like to have something like the PickerTreeView.aspx, but instead of selecting lists select the lists' columns. Note that I don't want the column's value, I want the actual column.

Would this have to be done with a custom column and by editing my list's forms? (Edit/New)

I'm assuming something like this: http://blog.sandippatil.com/list-item-tree-view-in-sharepoint/ would be helpful to create the tree view.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How I would approach this is the following:

1. Create a custom field type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862248.aspx. This includes an xml definition and a class inheriting from SPField. Your field type would handling storing some sort of representation of the column as a string (Maybe ListName;ColumnName) and then resolving that representation to the actual list and column.
2. Create a custom field control for you custom field type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861838.aspx. This is a class that inherits from BaseFieldControl, and handles actually transforming your field data into something the user interacts with
3. Create a custom rendering template http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862055.aspx. This is the markup that works with your field control to actually render something out.